# Swift 5 very random and hardly identifiable crashes

Tags: swift, swift4, swift5, libdispatch

My crash log from firebase unfortunately doesnt really help me finding a solution to my issue.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  MyApp                           0x94d30 PostsAPI.loadNewestPosts(ordering:start:limit:onSuccess:) + 4306505008 (<compiler-generated>:4306505008)
1  MyApp                           0x5f8ec OverviewVC.loadNewestPosts(more:) + 4306286828 (<compiler-generated>:4306286828)
2  MyApp                           0x6393c partial apply for closure #2 in closure #1 in OverviewVC.loadNewestPosts(more:) + 4306303292 (<compiler-generated>:4306303292)
3  MyApp                           0x74a94 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4306373268 (<compiler-generated>:4306373268)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x6eec _dispatch_continuation_pop + 500
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a13c _dispatch_source_invoke + 1596
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x11e9c _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 756
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x11b98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
9  CoreFoundation                 0x51800 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
10 CoreFoundation                 0xb704 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
12 GraphicsServices               0x1374 GSEventRunModal + 164
13 UIKitCore                      0x514b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
14 UIKitCore                      0x296090 UIApplicationMain + 364
15 MyApp                           0x9a28 main + 20 (AppDelegate.swift:20)
16 ???                            0x102a59da4 (Fehlt)
```

As my code obviously doesn't have so many lines as the compiler tells me where it crashes. Any help is greatly appreciated as I cannot provoke this crash and it only happens randomly on some devices...

Comment: Showing the code of `PostsAPI.loadNewestPosts(ordering:start:limit:onSuccess:` might be a good start... Also, it doesn't appear in XCode/Organizer?

Comment: Do yourself a favour, and configure symbols properly on your firebase. Then instead of mysterious numbers, you will see the actual functions etc. Having said that, the crash gives enough clues to tell you the area of the code you should be looking at. Review`OverviewVC.loadNewestPosts(more:)` - it probably has a closure to call `PostsAPI.loadNewestPosts(ordering:start:limit:onSuccess:)`, which probably also has a closure. So something happens in between those 2 calls.

Comment: what is symbols? I looked upon the described code 1000 times and there is nothing wrong with it. I have tested with x devices, x accounts and everything and still it crashes randomly on only like 5 % of the users phone.

Comment: btw. i am using dSYMs, all other crashes show me the exact line of code but this one is the only one where extremely high numbers appear

Comment: @sfgblackwarkrts Since we see the method name, aren't they already symbolized? If you don't want to share the code of these method, it's fine, but we won't be able to help you then. Also, as I previously asked, they don't appear in XCode/Organizer? Sometimes, it's more precise on the real errorr (happened to to where Firebase was pointing me to a wrong direction).

Comment: I can share it. But can you explain me how I can see the crashes in the Xcode organizer? I only worked with the crash log from firebase console itself :/

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=nra79npr First link found with "Xcode organizer crash". On XCode, you open the Organizer Window, and go to the Crash tab/menu. You select the version, and see if there it is.